# Background Tasks in Spring (AMQP)

Tags: spring-amqp, background-task

I need to handle a time-consuming and error-prone task (e.g., invoking a SOAP endpoint that will trigger the delivery of an SMS) whenever a given endpoint of my REST API is invoked, but I'd prefer not to make my users wait for that before sending a response back. Spring AMQP is already part of my stack, so I though about leveraging it to establish a "work queue" and have a number of worker processes consuming from the queue and taking care of the "work units". I have, however, the following requirements:

1. A work unit is guaranteed to be delivered, and delivered to exactly one worker.
2. Shall a work unit fail to be completed for any reason it must get placed back in the queue so that another worker can pick it up later.
3. Work units survive server reboots and crashes. This is mandatory because I won't be using a DB of any kind to store them.

I know RabbitMQ and Spring AMQP can be configured in such a way that ensures these three requirements, but I've only ever used it to achieve RPC so I don't know much about anything other than that. Is there any example I might follow? What are some of the pitfalls to watch out for?

Comment: See the [rabbitmq tutorials](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html); Spring AMQP supports all the patterns. The listener container will give you the resiliency you need.

Answer (score 0):

While creating queues, rabbitmq gives you two options; transient or durable. Durable messages will be available until you acknowledge them. And messages won't expire if you do not give queue a ttl. For starters you can enable rabbitmq management plugin and play around a little.

But if you really want to guarantee the safety of your messages against hard resets or hardware problems, i guess you need to use a rabbitmq cluster.

[Rabbitmq Clustering](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html) and you can find high availability subject on the right side of the page.

This guy explaines [how to cluster](http://blog.flux7.com/blogs/tutorials/how-to-creating-highly-available-message-queues-using-rabbitmq)

By the way i like beanstalkd too. You can make it write messages to disk and they will be safe except disk failures.